# How to know which the software's version will be installed by ubuntu make?

Tags: arduino, ubuntu-make

Today was released a new version of Arduino IDE (1.6.9). I think Ubuntu Make hasn't still been updated. But, how could I know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Make says it fetches the latest upstream development release, and compiles it from source. If the Arduino download site has been updated for the new release, Ubuntu Make should use it automatically.